# VolleyError doesnt give response

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using the code below to notify the user about the an error:

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Keine Internetverbindung", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            // TODO
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            // TODO
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            // TODO
        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the Application and shut down all the connections I don't get the Toast. There should be the NoConnectionError-Toast, but nothing happens.

Comment: Does it work if you shut down all the connections and THEN start the app?

Comment: Depending on how you remove the internet, the issue could be that you don't receive a timeout error from `Volley`. How do you remove the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have missed to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest file you should ideally get `NoConnectionError` if there is no internet connection.

In case, no wifi, no 2G,3G, etc, I have

[image]

else you would get if you have not declared `Internet` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

See if this helps!